# set the initial selected value inside a select tag in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set the initial value inside a select tag like this but it doesn't work:

```html
<select [ngModel]="myViewModel" (change)="onViewModelChanged($event.target.value)" style="width:100%;height:30px">
    <option *ngFor="let data of myViewModel" [selected]="data.name == 'Select'" [value]="data.name">{{data.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `[selected]` when already using `ngModel`. Here is a version, which should work:

```html
<select [ngModel]="selectedValue" (change)="onViewModelChanged($event.target.value)" style="width:100%;height:30px">
    <option *ngFor="let data of myViewModel" [value]="data.name">{{data.name}}</option>
</select>
```

And in your code just set the variable you bind to the model:

```ts
selectedValue: string = myViewModel[0].name;
```